# Android Studio listview item with heart image, click to add item in favorites

Tags: android, listview

please help me.

I've **ListView**  with heart **ImageView**.I want to change color of heart Image as red when I click heart image.then I want to display all item that click in the favorites.it just like bookmark ListView item

here is the output.

[image]

Here is my code.

**FragmentOne**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, container, false);

        TabHost host = (TabHost) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        host.setup();

        //Tab 1
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("SONG LIST");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        spec.setIndicator("SONG LIST");
        host.addTab(spec);

            ArrayList<FragmentOne_slResults> slResults = GetSearchResults();
        final ListView sllv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.slListView);
        sllv.setAdapter(new FragmentOne_Adapter(getActivity(), slResults));


        //Tab 2
        spec = host.newTabSpec("NEW SONGS");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        spec.setIndicator("NEW SONGS");
        host.addTab(spec);

        //Tab 3
        spec = host.newTabSpec("FAVORITES");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        spec.setIndicator("FAVORITES");
        host.addTab(spec);

        return rootView;
    }

    //SONG LIST
    private ArrayList<FragmentOne_slResults> GetSearchResults(){
        ArrayList<FragmentOne_slResults> results = new ArrayList<FragmentOne_slResults>();

        FragmentOne_slResults slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 1 Song Title 1 Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 1");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 1");
        slr.setNumber("123456");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 2 Song Title 2 Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 2");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 2");
        slr.setNumber("12356");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 3");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 3");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 3");
        slr.setNumber("12456");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 2");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 2");
        slr.setNumber("1256");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 2 Song Title 2 Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 3");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 3");
        slr.setNumber("1233");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 2");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 2");
        slr.setNumber("12456");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 2 Song Title 2 Title 2 Song Title 2 Song Title 2 Title 23 tle 2 Song Title 2 Song Title 2 Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 3");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 3");
        slr.setNumber("123456");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 2");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 2");
        slr.setNumber("123456");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 3");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 3");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 3");
        slr.setNumber("123456");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 2");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 2");
        slr.setNumber("1256");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 3");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 3");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 3");
        slr.setNumber("123456");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 2");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 2");
        slr.setNumber("123456");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 3");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 3");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 3");
        slr.setNumber("123456");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 2");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 2");
        slr.setNumber("123456");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 3");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 3");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 3");
        slr.setNumber("1236");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 2");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 2");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 2");
        slr.setNumber("123456");
        results.add(slr);

        slr = new FragmentOne_slResults();
        slr.setTitle("Song Title 3");
        slr.setArtist("Artist 3");
        slr.setVolume("Vol 3");
        slr.setNumber("123456");
        results.add(slr);

        return results;
    }
```

**FragmentOne_Adapter**

```
package com.magicstarme.virtualsongbook;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Joe on 6/29/2016.
 */
public class FragmentOne_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static ArrayList<FragmentOne_slResults> oneslArrayList;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public FragmentOne_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<FragmentOne_slResults> slresults) {
        oneslArrayList = slresults;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return oneslArrayList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return oneslArrayList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one_slview, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.txtArtist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.artist);
            holder.txtVolume = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.volume);
            holder.txtNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.number);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtTitle.setText(oneslArrayList.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.txtArtist.setText(oneslArrayList.get(position).getArtist());
        holder.txtVolume.setText(oneslArrayList.get(position).getVolume());
        holder.txtNumber.setText(oneslArrayList.get(position).getNumber());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtArtist;
        TextView txtVolume;
        TextView txtNumber;
    }
}
```

here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:paddingRight="5dip">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/framelayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/title"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="17dp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </FrameLayout>

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/framelayout2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/volume"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="15dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="right|top" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/artist"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="15dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="left|top" />

                    </FrameLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/relativeLayout3">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:paddingTop="5dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/mic"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|top" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/heart"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|top" />

            </FrameLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#cccccc"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:background="#cccccc">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/number"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

            </FrameLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>-->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="3
        ">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/framelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/framelayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/artist"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/volume"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right|top"/>

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/relativeLayout3">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/mic"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/heart"
                android:layout_gravity="right|top" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="#cccccc">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/number"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

please help me.

I am developing an songbook application like **digital songbook** from playstore.

thanks,

joe

Comment: you can set one flag for all item if flag is true then make it red otherwise as it is

Comment: Can you provide you layout for the list items?

Comment: please see edit. can anyone give me sample code. im sorry im just new to android. hope you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my code for changing color of heart. In your layout xml file use this

```
<ToggleButton
     android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
     style="@style/toggleButton"
     android:layout_width="40dp"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:layout_gravity="right"
     android:background="@drawable/favourite_toggle_bg"/>
```

In style file add this.

```
<style name="toggleButton"  parent="@android:Theme.Black">
    <item name="android:buttonStyleToggle">@style/Widget.Button.Toggle</item>
    <item name="android:textOn"></item>
    <item name="android:textOff"></item>
</style>
```

create new file in favourite_toggle_bg.xml in drawable folder and add this code.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_checked="false"
              android:drawable="@mipmap/favourite_no" />
        <item android:state_checked="true"
              android:drawable="@mipmap/favourite_yes" />
    </selector>
```

Add ToggleButton btnFavourite into your holder and initilize this with ToggleButton

```
holder.btnFavourite = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
```

In java code if you want to favorite Toggle button check then add this in your getView adapter method

```
holder.btnFavourite.setChecked(true);
```

Comment: thanks for this code. this is better but when i click the heart, two heart will turn to red and when i scroll, it moves to other heart. another thing is when i refresh and go to other fragment the red will become grey heart again. please help me.

Comment: hi @asim please help me. how can i set holder.btnFavourite.setChecked(true); when i list data from listview.

Comment: Add IsFavourite boolean variable in FragmentOne_slResults class. Initialize it with false and when user click on favorite button set it true  oneslArrayList.get(position).IsFavourite=true. and in your getView method change favourite button according to this IsFavourite value like this if(IsFavourite?holder.btnFavourite.setChecked(true) : holder.btnFavourite.setChecked(false)).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding it as an ImageButton in the Viewholder, and then add a SetOnclickListener in the getView for it?

```
holder.button = (ImageButton)convertView.findviewById( ... );
final ImageButton tmp = holder.button;
tmp.setOnClickListenet( ... ) ;
```

EDIT: 
In your XML instead of:

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/heart"
            android:layout_gravity="right|top" />
```

Replace it with:

```
<ImageButton
android:id  < add your ID here !!! >
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/heart"
            android:layout_gravity="right|top" />
```

Comment: thanks, can give me more codes? sorry im new to android. hope you understand.

Comment: Give the heart icon an ID in your XML. Declare it as a Button in the ViewHolder. The getview converts the Viewholder to usable Views, there you can initialize your actions. A final tmp is needed because you cannot modify the object in its own inner loop. THe ViewHolder is just a template which gets "inflated" into a proper View in the getview, so to say.

I advise you read about the ViewHolder pattern to understand how it works.

EDIT: Just saw your XML. The Heart icon should be a button instead of an ImageView.

Comment: thank you. now what code i need to add inside `tmp.setOnClickListenet( ... ) ;` to change src of the imageview from heart to heartred? please help. thanks.

Comment: tmp.setbackgroundresource

Comment: i do this, but im gertting error. `tmp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(tmp.getTag().toString()) == 1) {
                        tmp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.heartred);
                        tmp.setTag(2);
                    } else {
                        tmp.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.heart);
                        tmp.setTag(1);
                    }

                }
            });`